# Initially Sort Sales Order Customer Lookup on acctName

Tags: c#, acumatica

I'm attempting to initially sort the customer lookup by account name.
In the DAC, I selected SO.SOrder, customized the attributes by selecting "Replace Original", and added this:

`[PXDefault]
[CustomerActive(typeof(Search<BAccountR.bAccountID,Where<Customer.type, IsNotNull,
Or<Current<SOOrder.aRDocType>, Equal<ARDocType.noUpdate>,
And<BAccountR.type, Equal<BAccountType.companyType>>>>, OrderBy<Asc<BAccountR.acctName>>>),
Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible, DescriptionField = typeof(Customer.acctName), Filterable = true)]`

Notice I added , `OrderBy<Asc<BAccountR.acctName>>`.

After a successful build and opening SOOrder screen, I get this error:

```
Error: The parameter length exceeds the allowed value.
Parameter name: types 
   at PX.Data.BqlCommand.Compose(Type[] types) 
   at PX.Objects.AR.CustomerAttribute..ctor(Type search, Type[] fields) 
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute._CreateCaObject(RuntimeModule pModule, IRuntimeMethodInfo pCtor, Byte** ppBlob, Byte* pEndBlob, Int32* pcNamedArgs) 
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.CreateCaObject(RuntimeModule module, IRuntimeMethodInfo ctor, IntPtr& blob, IntPtr blobEnd, Int32& namedArgs) 
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, Int32 pcaCount, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean.
```

The Search method does have an overload that accepts the OrderBy. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help.

--Paul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things to mention here:

The first problem you are going to have is a selector is only ordered by the key value making your end goal not acheivable:

[Modify Selector Default Sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47205078/modify-selector-default-sorting)

The second is the error message. The problem appears to be an Acumatica bug in `CustomerAttribute` when its building the `BqlCommand` at runtime on sales order. In constructor `CustomerAttribute(Type search, params Type[] fields)` there is a statement that checks `searchType == typeof(Search<,,>)`and then tries to build the query using `Search2<Field, Join, Where>` when it should be using `Search2<Field, Join, Where, OrderBy>` including the OrderBy. I have confirmed the error goes away with my own custom version of this class used in place of the original but the order by will not change on your selector. As a result a fix will not help your end goal.

```
// ...
else if (searchType == typeof(Search<,,>)) //when Search<Field, Where, OrderBy>
{
    cmd = BqlCommand.Compose(
                    typeof(Search2<,,>), //need Search2<Field, Join, Where, OrderBy> 
                           //   however using Search2<Field, Join, Where> and results in an error
                    typeof(BAccountR.bAccountID),
                    typeof(LeftJoin<,,>),
                    typeof(Customer),
                    typeof(On<Customer.bAccountID, Equal<BAccountR.bAccountID>, And<Match<Customer, Current<AccessInfo.userName>>>>),
                    typeof(LeftJoin<,,>),
                    typeof(Contact),
                    typeof(On<Contact.bAccountID, Equal<BAccountR.bAccountID>, And<Contact.contactID, Equal<BAccountR.defContactID>>>),
                    typeof(LeftJoin<,,>),
                    typeof(Address),
                    typeof(On<Address.bAccountID, Equal<BAccountR.bAccountID>, And<Address.addressID, Equal<BAccountR.defAddressID>>>),
                    typeof(LeftJoin<,>),
                    typeof(Location),
                    typeof(On<Location.bAccountID, Equal<BAccountR.bAccountID>, And<Location.locationID, Equal<BAccountR.defLocationID>>>),
                    searchArgs[1],
                    searchArgs[2]);
}
// ...
```

Comment: Thank you. This helps going forward.

Comment: Glad to help. Do not forget to mark as answer if you feel this resolves your issue. Thanks